# Multiples condiciones en un switch

Tags: javascript, switch

Se puede hacer usar dos condiciones en el switch? Si la rta es si , como?

```
switch (condicion1 y condicion2) { // en esta parte pregunto
     case "x":
        ....
        break;
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me imagino que tienes 2 dos variables recibidas, las puedes englobar asi:

```
   var locos = 12;
   var doctores = 3

   switch (locos,doctores) {
     case doctores== locos:
       alert('son iguales')
       break;
       case locos != doctores:
       alert('hay que contratar mas doctoroes')
       break;
   
     default:
      alert('Los doctores son suficientes')
       break;
   }
```

Checalo y me dices